# Different behavior of "each" method in development and production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

I have table in my ERB-template. Like this:

```
<table>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= user.id %></td>
      <td><%= user.name %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

It works fine. Suppose I have 2 users.

Table will be like this:

> 1 | foo
>
> 2 | bar

But for example, I decide to edit user with id1.

In development it will be correct. Like this:

> 1 | oof
>
> 2 | bar

But in production it will be:

> 2 | bar
>
> 1 | oof

After editing user always jumps to the end of table.

I think it because I use SQLite in local but Heroku uses PostgreSQL.

I'm newbie, so I can be wrong.

My question is: how should I change my code to make the code work correctly everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly specify order in your controller. If the order is unspecified, PostgreSQL does not guarantee any order, so assume it will be randomized.

```
@users = User.order(:id)#.limit/pagination
```

I would also advise you to have the same databases in development and production, if you take some time to setup PostgreSQL locally, it will pay off.